# Attach event handler to element inside google maps info bubble

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a question regarding google maps and event handling/listening.

Using jQuery and google maps v3, I am able to place a map marker and an event listener that opens an infobubble when the user clicks on the marker.  What I'd like to do (but so far haven't been able to figure out) is add another event handler to the contents of the info bubble.  For example, if the user clicks on the map marker open the info bubble (that part works), and then if they click on something inside the infobubble do something else.  I have pasted my code below, thanks in advance for any help

```
function addMarker(data) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);
    var title = data.title? data.title: "";
    var icon = $('#siteUrl').val() + 'img/locate.png';

var bubbleContentString = "<span class=\"bubble-details-button\">Get Details about " + title+ "</span>";

myInfoBubble = new InfoBubble({
    content: bubbleContentString,
    hideCloseButton: true,        
    backgroundColor: '#004475',
    borderColor: '#004475'
});

var myMarker =  new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: title,
        icon: icon
    });    
addListenerToMarker(myMarker, myInfoBubble);
markerSet.push(myMarker, myInfoBubble);    
}
function addListenerToMarker(marker, bubble){
    console.log($(bubble.getContent()).find('.bubble-details-button')[0]);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
        if (!bubble.isOpen()) {  
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(bubble, 'domready', function(){ 
                console.log($(bubble.getContent()).find('.bubble-details-button')[0]);
                google.maps.event.addDomListener($(bubble.getContent()).find('.bubble-details-button')[0], 'click', function(){ 
                    alert("hi"); 
                }); 
            });
            bubble.open(map, marker); 
        }     
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to add `"click"` event on element ,which is not `DOM Element`. `$('.bubble-details-button')` is not `DOM Element` (it is a wrapper of `DOM Element`), but `$('.bubble-details-button')[0]` is.

On the other hand, when you are trying to add `"click"` event, the content is not created yet. You can work(e.g. add events) with content's elements ,only when they are already created. The `InfoBubble` will trigger `"domready"` event, when its content will be created.So you need to handle it:

```
 if (!bubble.isOpen()) {
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(bubble, 'domready', function(){
        google.maps.event.addDomListener($(bubble.getContent()).find('.bubble-details-button')[0], 'click', function(){
            alert("hi");
        });
    });
    bubble.open(map, mymarker);        
}
```

Comment: What you are saying makes sense, however I tried implementing your suggestion and I wasn't successful.

I did a copy and paste of your suggestion however the bubble itself doesn't open so I'm not able to even click on the contents inside the bubble

Comment: Sorry, that's not exactly true.  There was a typo in my original code.  I fixed that typo, it was in the line where I had the call to google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
marker should have read, mymarker.

However, fixing the typo results in an error when i click on the marker in the map, the error message is:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'addEventListener': object is null or undefined

Comment: Sorry,for late reply. Could you check this `console.log($(bubble.getContent()).find('.bubble-details-button')[0])` ? Is it DOM Element?

Comment: no need to apoligize, thank you for your reply.

I get the following:

    LOG: undefined 



I feel like I'm not giving you the whole story.  

The code i originally posted was slightly simplified, because I'm actually going through an array of markers and adding the 
listeners through another event (otherwise I wind up with each bubble getting the same content).  



i've edited the code above (pending peer review for some reason) to reflect the actual working code that i am using.

Comment: I think that there's a separate issue with my code, as I've tried this in another project as a test and it works, i'll do some debugging to trace the error, but as far as the original question goes this solution works, thanks for your help

Comment: @Engineer Thanks you very much ! The propsed solution works well with Google Map v3 & InfoBubble from google-maps-utility-library-v3

Answer (score 3):

In scenarios where I have to do what you are describing, I include a JavaScript function call directly in the InfoBubble content. I often include hyperlinks within an InfoBubble, so in that case I do the following: 1 - Write a JavaScript function to handle a hyperlink click. 2 - Create the marker. 3 - Attach a click event handler to the marker that opens an InfoBubble. 4 - Define the content of the InfoBubble so that JavaScript embedded directly in the InfoBubble content is set to handle the click event by calling the JavaScript function that was defined in Step #1 - something like:

```
"<span>" +
     "<a href='javascript:showDetail(" + param1 + "," + param2 + ");'>" + 
      displayTextContent + "</a>" +
"</span>"
```

Comment: oh nice..hahahaha...how could i forget this simeple solution ..Thanks :)