# Backbone Event not firing - Google Maps InfoBubble

Tags: google-maps, backbone.js

I am trying to trigger an event off a click inside a Google Infobubble inside a Google Map.

```
class MapSite.Views.Maps extends Backbone.View

  events:
    'click [name=testdrive]' : 'initControls'

  initialize: ->
    @render()

  render: ->
    @el = $("#map")  
    $this = $(this.el)
    @loadMap()

  initControls: ->
    alert "hello"

  loadMap: ->
    osmMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(
      getTileUrl: (coord, zoom) ->
        "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/#{zoom}/#{coord.x}/#{coord.y}.png"
      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
      isPng: true
      alt: "OpenStreetMap layer"
      name: "OSM"
      maxZoom: 19
    )

    cloudMadeMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(
      getTileUrl: (coord, zoom) ->
        "http://b.tile.cloudmade.com/****/54912/256/#{zoom}/#{coord.x}/#{coord.y}.png"
      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
      isPng: true
      alt: "CloudMade layer"
      name: "CMade"
      maxZoom: 13
    )

    lat = 51.503
    lng = -0.113
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
    options =
      zoom: 10
      center: latlng
      mapTypeId: 'OSM'
    @gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options)
    @gMap.mapTypes.set('OSM', osmMapType)
    @gMap.mapTypes.set('CloudMade', cloudMadeMapType)
    @gMap.setMapTypeId('CloudMade')


    @initShape()
    @initLabel()



initLabel: ->
    console.log("This is where the label should appear")
    initLabel = new InfoBubble(
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.44115356738888, 0.14849636779354114)
      maxWidth: 240
      maxHeight: 210
      shadowStyle: 1
      padding: 0
      content: '<div class="tooltip_header"><h4>Hello</h4></div><div class="tooltip_content"><p>Nunc nec, egestas vel augue rhoncus massa cras, tincidunt a nisi nisi est lundium non sed? Eros pulvinar</p></div> <div id="tooltip_buttons" class="tooltip_buttons"><button class="btn btn-success" name="testdrive">Test Drive</button> <button class="btn btn-warning">Read More</button></div>',
      tabPadding: 12
      backgroundColor: 'black'
      borderRadius: 0
      arrowSize: 10
      borderWidth: 0
      borderColor: '#AB2424'
      disableAutoPan: true
      hideCloseButton: false
      arrowPosition: 0.5
      backgroundClassName: 'phoney'
      tabClassName: 'tabClass'
      activeTabClassName: 'activeTabClass'
      arrowStyle: 2
      )

    initLabel.open(@gMap)
```

end

The Map loads great, and the info bubble is there. I then try and take 

and link an event to it being clicked, but it is not firing. I have set the el to be "#map" and the div for the infobubble sits inside the map div.

Essentially all I need to end up with is an event that gets fired when a click is made on the button inside the info bubble. I think this might be because Backbone doesn't see the info bubble because it gets loaded afterwards so cant attach itself?

Answer (score 0):

By default events in a backbone view are bound to the root `el` using *event delegation*. Being that you are switching your `el` afterwards the events "lost".

What you can try doing is *reDelegateging* your events using the [delegateEvents](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents) method.

As a side point, I see that you are caching `$(this.el)`,this is no longer necessary as you can now use [$el](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-%24el) instead (I think as of backbone.js 0.9.2).

Comment: You should be able to just call the method (something like `this.delegateEvents()`) after you assign your `el` to `#maps`

Comment: hmmm that does not seem to work either... Is it perhaps the fact it is inside GOogle Maps? and not a standard div. And the fact that it is created after the delegateevents?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference that it is created after the `delegateEvents` (but you can definitely try calling it afterwards). Are you sure that your button is a child element of the `#maps div`?

Comment: yeah even if I have the el to #tooltip_buttons which is the div the button sits inside it does not want to work. This is really odd!

Comment: also it is inside #map - its quite deep in there but it is in there!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060275/attach-event-handler-to-element-inside-google-maps-info-bubble this may be the reason!