# Attaching jQuery dialog to InfoBubble in Google Maps marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-dialog, infobubble

I am coding with google maps v3. I would like to add jQuery and attach event handlers into infoBubble (a customizable infoWindow jscript extension I got [here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html)).

Specifically, I want to have users click on a link in the infoBubble and have a dialog form pop up using jQuery-UI. The dialog form will prompt users for input, which will subsequently be stored in MySQL.

I have been stuck with this for a month. This was the closest thing I came to:

[Attach event handler to element inside google maps info bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060275/attach-event-handler-to-element-inside-google-maps-info-bubble)

Below is my javascript function used to create the map markers:

*(**Note**: The idea is if attaching the event-handler to infoBubble works, I would replace `function() {alert("hi!");}` with the jQuery-UI form. But it doesn't work. I have tried using "`var str = 'onClick=formPopUp()';`" but javascript does not support prompt dialog forms with multiple entries. Also, I don't really know how to have jQuery-UI calls inside a javascript function like formPopUp(). Sorry if it's confusing)*

```
function createMarker(map, latlng, fields, name) {
      var str = "id='user-creates'";

      var html = "<b><font size='5'>" + fields["name"] + "</font></b>" + "</br>" + 
             "<font size='2'>" + fields["google_rating"] + " / 5.00" + "</font>" + "</br>" + 
                 "<font size='2'>" + fields["type"] + "</font>" + "</br>" + 
                 "<font size='2'>" + "Hours" + "</font>" + "</br>" + 
                 "</br>" + 
                 "</br>" +
                 "<font size='2'>" + "Top Reviews " + "(<i>" + fields["num_reviews"] + " Reviews</i>)" +  "</font>" + "</br>" + 
                 "<div " + str + ">" +  "Example</div>" + 
                 "</br>" + 
                 "</br>" + 
                 "<font size='2'>" + "Photos " + "(<i>0 Photos</i>)" + "</font>" + "</br>" +
                 "</br>" + 
                 "</br>" +
                 "<font size='2'>" + "Friends Who've Been Here " + "(<i>0 Friends</i>)" + "</font>" + "</br>" +
                 "</br>" + 
                 "</br>" +
                 "<font size='2'>" + fields["address"] + "</font>" + "</br>" + 
                 "<font size='2'>" + fields["phone_num"] + "</font>" + "</br>" + 
                 "<font size='2'><a href=" + fields["web_url"] + "Website" + "</a></font>";


      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng
      });

      infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
            map: map,
            position: latlng,
            borderColor: '#D14836',
            borderWidth: 4,     
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoBubble.setContent(html);

        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infoBubble, 'domready', function(){
             //jQuery code here
             google.maps.event.addDomListener($(infoBubble.getContent()).find('#user-creates')[0], 
                                'click', function() {alert("hi!")}); 

        });

        infoBubble.open(map, marker); 

        });

    }
```

Comment: I haven't seen the `<font>` tag used for a while. You may want to look at using [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) instead.

Comment: It's just a crude prototype. I plan to use CSS going forward. For now I just want to the diaglog box to pop up. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

This string:

```
var str = 'id=user-creates';
```

Is not the correct format for embedding in HTML.

It needs to be:

```
var str = "id='user-creates'";
```

Comment: Hey geocodezip,it was actually a typo in my post. I've had the correct format and it still not working.

Comment: Please compare your version to mine.

Comment: Hey geocodezip, this is embarrassing. A re-typo. I have triple-checked my code and yes I have your suggested format. It is still not working. This time an infoBubble does not even open up. Thanks so much again.